# XDG_DATA_DIRS env variable using two separator types in fish shell

Tags: opensuse, fish, snap, xdg

After doing an OS upgrade (opensuse leap 15.2 -> 15.3), my XDG setup broke. Among other things, my `XDG_DATA_DIR` env var uses two different value separators: `:` and  .

Current XDG_DATA_DIRS value:

```
/home/bernard/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop /var/lib/snapd/desktop
```

When looking for the code that populates this variable, I came across scripts in `/etc/profile.d/`, but from debugging the `snapd.sh` one, it doesn't seem to be causing the deficiency. I modified `snapd.sh` and I printed the variable into a `/tmp/var` at the script start and script end. By observing the results it looks as if this script wasn't changing anything in `XDG_DATA_DIRS`.

snap version: `2.54.1`

fish version: `3.3.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about the dot: I think you'll have to dig into which process is adding that.

The last directory element separated by a space is telling though. It seems you're adding a directory to XDG_DATA_DIRS in fish and expecting subprocess to get a colon-separated value. fish does that automatically only for [PATH variables](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#path-variables).

In your fish config, try this before you do any manipulation of that variable:

```
set --path -x XDG_DATA_DIRS $XDG_DATA_DIRS
```

Comment: Placing that in `~/.config/fish/config.fish` has fixed it for me. Thank you!